# Javascript shorthand way to assign true/false to variable if a array element exists

Tags: javascript

I was hoping I could just assign true / false to a variable if my element exists in an associative array.

I tried this --

```
var finalDisExist = stepsArray['stepIDFinal'];
```

-- of course this does exactly what you would think it does (assigning the object to the variable.

But I am pretty sure I have seen something close to this before, can someone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks!
Todd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps, the quickest and best way is `stepsArray.hasOwnProperty('stepIDFinal')`.

**NB:** Do NOT use `'stepIDFinal' in stepsArray`, since this will check the entire prototype chain for your "hashmap" object and detect `toString` among others...

Comment: ...scratch that, you're right. I was thinking of... not sure what. Although checking `'stepIDFinal' in stepsArray` wouldn't be an issue since there's no native `stepIDFinal` property on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @amnotiam: right, yet I believe it's not the only key OP might want to use :) And we've hit this "toString"-ish issue a few times while using the `in` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
var finalDisExist = !!stepsArray['stepIDFinal'];
```

The first negation takes everything that was falsy (like `undefined` and `0`) into true and the second one to *real* false - and vice versa. This means if `stepsArray['stepIDFinal']` is equal to `null` or `0`, `finalDisExist` will be `false`...

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `stepsArray.hasOwnProperty("stepIDFinal")` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
var finalDisExist = !!stepsArray['stepIDFinal'];
```

or maybe

```
var finalDisExist = "undefined" !== typeof stepsArray['stepIDFinal'];
```

?